# Browse git repository over Webdav (debian)

Tags: debian, git, webdav

I would like to be able to browse a (bare) git repository over Webdav.
Note that I do not want to be able to push/pull over Webdav. Instead, I actually want to be able to browse through my files via Webdav, without the need to check out.
My git repository is on a server running Debian.

Is there any software that allows for that?

Comment: Git doesn’t use WebDAV. You may be confused because SVN implements some parts of WebDAV/DeltaV.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answers to these questions:

- [Best Free Git Web Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2131390/428779)
- [What's the best Web interface for Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/438163/428779)

[Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/) comes up often, though.

Comment: It seems that none of these web interfaces support Webdav. I would prefer Webdav, as it is easier to integrate with Android and Windows.